# Get SUM from CATEGORY and by MONTH

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

So I'm trying to sort some data from a form in google sheets. I need to sort the data by category. and by the month.
So far I have been able to sort these individually but not in the same cell.

my code so far for my test form is below the image.

[image]

To Filter by a category, in **F2**:
`=UNIQUE(B2:B25)`

for cells **G2** and below I used: `=SUMIF(B$2:B$25,F2,C$2:C$25)`

to get the **TOTAL** for entire categories I used: `=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(spending_response!D2:D100)=5)*(YEAR(spending_response!D2:D100)=2020)*(spending_response!C2:C100))`

my problem is I can't put these two together. I tried adding the two codes in the same cell separate by a comma but it doesn't seem to work. please see the below image for what I am using this for and dismiss the test values.

[image]

Comment: does putting this in G2 and drag downwards work? : `=SUMPRODUCT((spending_response!$B$2:$B$100=F2)*(MONTH(spending_response!$D$2:$D$100)=5)*(YEAR(spending_response!$D$2:$D$100)=2020)*(spending_response!$C$2:$C$100))`

Comment: @p._phidot_ SOLVED. Thanking you kindly!! Can you post this as an answer so I can mark it as solved? thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in G2 and drag downwards :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((spending_response!$B$2:$B$100=F2)*(MONTH(spending_response!$D$2:$D$100)=5)*(YEAR(spending_response!$D$2:$D$100)=2020)*(spending_response!$C$2:$C$100))
```

Idea : add another draggable 'checking' criteria to the sumproduct. /(^_^)

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=QUERY(A2:C, "select A,sum(B) where month(C)+1=5 group by A label sum(B)''", 0)
```

[image: 0]